# Convert a mysql date (datetime) into a better date format using php

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date

I some php code which gets info from a mysql database. The problem is that the date is coming out in the format : `"2010-02-03 22:21:26"`

Does anyone know a simple solution to make the date more user friendly format. e.g

```
2nd march 2010 at 22:21.
```

Comment: I think it is better to save dates in unix timestamp so you can manipulate them easier.

Comment: @Axel: I don't think so. There is reason why DATETIME exists. PHP can also handle ISO-dates and also has a datetime-class. http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: If this is PHP5 you can use `strtotime()` but PHP4 won't support that format... is this PHP4 you're working with?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

e.g., `2010-02-03 22:21:26` to `3rd February 2010 at 22:21`:

```
$DateTimeStr = '2010-02-03 22:21:26';
echo date('jS F Y \a\t G:i', strtotime($DateTimeStr));
```

Answer (score 2):

date() function will assist you in this.

Something like

```
$date = date('j F, Y h:i:s', strtotime($date_value));
print $date;
```

Format options:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2):

Or use the [datetime-class](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).