# Date conversion for PHP & MySql

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I am getting date from an XML feed in the below format

```
Wed, 12 Jun 2013 06:13:37 -0400
```

How can I convert this date in PHP to insert into MySQL database as

```
2013-06-12 06:13:37
```

Comment: please see this: [Convert a mysql date (datetime) into a better date format using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533589/convert-a-mysql-date-datetime-into-a-better-date-format-using-php?rq=1)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `date` function, along with `strtotime`:

```
$dateVar = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("Wed, 12 Jun 2013 06:13:37 -0400") );
```

Alternatively, you can use the `DateTime` class:

```
$s = new DateTime("Wed, 12 Jun 2013 06:13:37 -0400");
$dateVar = $s->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: This works fine but can you guide me in converting the -0400 also to GMT? Currently with the above lines of code, the mysql date is '2013-06-12 00:00:00'

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$originalDate = "Wed, 12 Jun 2013 06:13:37 -0400";
$newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($originalDate));

echo $newDate; // will display 2013-06-12 13:13:37
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$date = 'Wed, 12 Jun 2013 06:13:37 -0400';
$mysql_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date)); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = strtotime("Wed, 12 Jun 2013 06:13:37 -0400");
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$time);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can often use PHPs function strtotime() but if you know the format you should use 
[date_create_from_format() || DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
$FromStr = 'Wed, 12 Jun 2013 06:13:37 -0400';
$Date = DateTime::createFromFormat($FromStr,'D, d M Y H:i:s O');
print date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$Date);
```

You should look at the format documentation. You may want to change your timezone parameter (O i my example)

Answer (score 0):

Only because no one seems to have mentioned it already, you also do something like this...

```
INSERT INTO my_table (dt) 
VALUES STR_TO_DATE('Wed, 12 Jun 2013 06:13:37 -0400','%a, %d %b %Y %h:%i:%s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php strtotime function as shown below